# Principle of inclusion and exclusion/ Matching

Tags: probability

I am finding hard to understand application of inclusion and exclusion in Matching problem? 
Suppose that n- n male-female couples are at a party and that the males and females are randomly paired for a dance ? what is the probability that none of the couple are paired together?

I don't understand why we have to take Union then use inc-ex principle to solve it?

Can some one help me to understand ?
Thank you

Comment: This is the problem of counting [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). [This PDF](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/184a_ch7slides_14-handout.pdf) has a pretty clear and elementary discussion. [This PDF](http://math.umn.edu/~jedyang/4707.13f/derangement.pdf) isn’t bad either.